# session not persisting with express-session in mobile website

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, session, express-session

I have a web app built using NodeJS ,Express and AngularJS.I am using **express-session** for maintaining login sessions.

In desktop browser,the login session persists,as expected,even after the browser is closed,but

> While accessing the website from mobile, the user gets
>   automatically logged out every time the mobile browser is closed.

Sample code is as following:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let session = require('express-session');
let MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    name: "test",
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: mongoConnectionUrl,
        ttl: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60, // = 2 days. Default 
        autoRemove: 'native'
    }),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

**How to stop auto logout of the user in mobile when the mobile browser is closed?**

Website facing the above issue: https://ayan.work/notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following code for configuration:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    name: "test",
    cookie: { maxAge: 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, //user won't have to login for 3 days
    store: new (require('express-sessions'))({
        storage: 'mongodb',
        instance: mongoose, // optional 
        host: 'localhost', // optional 
        port: 27017, // optional 
        db: 'database name', // optional 
        collection: 'sessions', // optional 
        expire: 86400 // optional 
    })
}));
```

The option `maxAge` will maintain data in cookie there.